# Best solution for implementing long pages in a walkthrough tutorial screen (UIPageViewController)

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uipageviewcontroller

I'm trying to implement a walkthrough tutorial screens when the user launches the app for the first time. I have no problem implementing it the issue is the walkthrough pages are longer (double the usual length of a normal screen) I thought of wrapping the UIImageView in a UIScrollView. Is that a good solution? Could it be done? done better?

Comment: Why would the pages be bigger than one screen-width?

Comment: @Mike the pages are not bigger than one screen-width, they're bigger than the screen-length

Comment: Sounds like you need to redesign the pages...

Comment: @Mike the requirement is that the user should be able to scroll up/down on each page to read the information provided.

Comment: Ah, so implement a UIPageViewController and each view controller therein should be a UIViewController with an embedded UIScrollView. (for what it's worth calling the height of the screen the "length" is slightly ambiguous)

Comment: use `BWWalkthrough`, it will help you do like 90% of walkthrough work in storyboard, very easy and nice